# Why can't I set oracle sessions value to 35?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, parameter, session

I want to simulate the error "ORA-00018.Maximum number of sessions exceed", so I want to limit the number of sessions to 35, and open serverl sqlplus to simulate this error, but sessions number didn't change

```
SQL> show parameter sessions;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -----------
java_max_sessionspace_size           integer     0
java_soft_sessionspace_limit         integer     0
license_max_sessions                 integer     0
license_sessions_warning             integer     0
sessions                             integer     248
shared_server_sessions               integer
```

change sessions from 248 to 35

```
SQL> alter system set sessions=35 scope=spfile;

System altered.

SQL> shutdown immediate;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
```

restart oracle instance

```
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1071333376 bytes
Fixed Size                  1375792 bytes
Variable Size             763363792 bytes
Database Buffers          301989888 bytes
Redo Buffers                4603904 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

Nothing changed

```
SQL> show parameter sessions;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -----------
java_max_sessionspace_size           integer     0
java_soft_sessionspace_limit         integer     0
license_max_sessions                 integer     0
license_sessions_warning             integer     0
sessions                             integer     248
shared_server_sessions               integer
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't change this value to 35, and how to simulate the "ORA-00018.Maximum number of sessions exceed" error?

Comment: sessions parameter is usually never set on a database. It's value depend on parameter `processes`.  So set `processes` to higher value, reset `sessions` and it will increase accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[SESSIONS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams234.htm#REFRN10197)

> Default value Derived: (1.5 * PROCESSES) + 22
>
> ...
>
> Oracle uses the default value of this parameter as its minimum. Values
>   between 1 and the default do not trigger errors, but Oracle ignores
>   them and uses the default instead.

If you want to decrease `sessions`, you need to decrease `processes` as well. Still, if you decrease processes, you will have plenty of 'free' sessions, and you will need to open several sessions until you receive the error.

Easiest way to simulate the error without messing with `processes` and opening several connections:

```
alter system set dispatchers = '(PROTOCOL=TCP)';
alter system set shared_servers = 1;
alter system set shared_server_sessions = 0;

$ sqlplus user/password@\'127.0.0.1:1521/orcl:shared\'

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sat May 21 11:38:41 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-00018: maximum number of sessions exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle database instance has several background sessions it creates in order to function, and those count against the number of sessions.  For example, here is an Oracle 12c instance, one user connected:

```
Prod:SYS> select type, count(*) from v$session group by type;

TYPE         COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
USER                1
BACKGROUND         34
```

And as others have mentioned, processes are interrelated with sessions, so if you set one, you probably need to set the other.